# RelativeLayout get out of adjust by inflating

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

In this piece of code I tried to set background for my relative layout, then I added a text view to the layout(in center of it), but when I run the application the text is not centered!

here is the java code:

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    createMainLayout();
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    RelativeLayout list = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main
    , null, false);
    mainLayout.addView(list);
    setContentView(mainLayout);
}

public void createMainLayout()
{
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),     
    R.drawable.background_pattern);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
    drawable.setTileModeXY(android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, 
    android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mainLayout.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

and here is my `activity_main`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

why is this happening? when I simply call `setContentView(R.Layout.activity_main)` beside `setContentView(mainLayout)` it displays correctly, but as expected there is no background for the layout.

Comment: remove this from textview android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

Comment: @IllegalArgument didn't solve the problem, it is still left_aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is here `inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);`. When using this function to inflate, the root view is not being considered. Here is the workaround;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

        <RelativeLayout         
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                android:textSize="70sp"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: tanx man, solved the problem, but is this logical to wrap a `RelativeLayout` into another one?

Comment: @Branky Here is a useful read. http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: @Branky Try `inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);` with everything else as they were already. Let me know if it works the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from textview:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
```

Comment: @Branky use android:layout_centerVertical="true" remove android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" or keep it if you need both

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" 
android:gravity="center" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```